# Good way to keep configs and simple data of android app

Tags: android, config

Read some articles, but cant find answer: **what is the best way to keep android app config and data?**  It must be a place, when the user press "clear app data" and setting stay available. Data also **must be available with first start**  and **dont create by app**... Thanks for help  and sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should Prefer SharedPreferences, go through this link you'll get good help http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html, and a simple basic Example [SharedPreferences](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/?ModPagespeed=noscript)

Comment: thanks, 1 link very usefull) sorry for offtop, maybe can write me names  android or xml java parses, which can edit (write, read,delete,paste) xml data?  found only link with DOM parse [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

Answer (score 0):

In case data shouldn/t be created and changed by app it would be easy to create a string-array in res/values/strings.xml and populate it with settings.

Comment: thanks, but this method does not work because need to edit the data